# Adjust Div to Be the Same Dimensions as the background-image

Tags: html, css

```
.dinosaur{
      background-image:url(images/dinosaur.png);
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      background-size:auto 300px;
      height:300;
      width:???;
      filter:hue-rotate(90deg) drop-shadow(10px 0px 5px black);
      float:left;
    }
```

I have a div with a background-image with a height of 300 and an automatic width. I want the div to the exact same dimensions as the background-image so it shows up like normal. If I don't include a width for the div or if I set it to automatic it doesn't work. What can I do to make the width of the div the exact same width of the background-image?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/300");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

```
width: 100%;
```

Would do the trick. Also the Height should bein `px`

Comment: Now the image takes up the entire line, which I don't want.

Comment: There's no way css can get the width of the background image you are using. You can try using `background-size: contain` with `background-repeat: no-repeat`. This will get the desired view you are expecting I guess. See I edited the original answer

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't do this by `background-image`. So you can try `img` tag inside div with `display: inline-flex`. So, now image's dimension is that div's width and height.

Here is example

```css
div {
  display: inline-flex
}
img {
  filter:hue-rotate(90deg) drop-shadow(10px 0px 5px black);
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.img{
  background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu');
  height: 300px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:auto 300px;
  filter:hue-rotate(90deg) drop-shadow(10px 0px 5px black);
}
```

```html
<div class="img"></div>
```

height value should be 300px. you have e typo there and remove the float property.